# Ordering an array element with using Struct and Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I need your help about my homework. Could anyone please help me to complete this. Actual the real question is that

Create a structure elem that contains one string, called name, up to 20 characters long, and a pointer to another elem that is called prev.  Write a main function that creates an array listelem which can store up to 10 elems, and fills it up in random order, with each element added pointing to the previously added element for prev. Then print out the list in the order the elements were input

For instance if the elements were entered in the order `9, 4, 2, 6, 3, 5, 0, 1, 7, 8` the output should be

```
listitem[9].name
listitem[4].name
listitem[2].name
...
```

You must use the prev data member of each element to print out the ordered list.

And my code is here, but It doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct elem Elem;
struct elem
{
    char name[20];
    struct elem *prev;
    struct elem *next;
};

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    srand(time(0));
    int listelem[10];
    printf("The elements of the array:\n");
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        listelem[i] = ( rand() % 10 )+1;
        printf("%d\n",listelem[i]);
    }
    Elem a = {listelem[0]};
    Elem b = {listelem[1],&a};
    Elem c = {listelem[2],&b,&d};
    Elem d = {listelem[3],&c,&e};
    Elem e = {listelem[4],&d,&f};
    Elem f = {listelem[5],&e,&g};
    Elem g = {listelem[6],&f,&h};
    Elem h = {listelem[7],&g,&x};
    Elem x = {listelem[8],&h,&y};
    Elem y = {listelem[9]};
    a.prev = NULL;
    b.prev = &a;
    c.prev = &b;
    d.prev = &c;
    e.prev = &d;
    f.prev = &e;
    g.prev = &f;
    h.prev = &g;
    x.prev = &h;
    y.prev = &x;
    Elem *q = &y;
    while(q->prev!=NULL) q=q->prev;
    do
    {
        printf("%s\n",q->name);
        q=q->next;
    }
    while(q!=NULL);
}
```

Comment: Look at this `Elem c = {listelem[2],&b,&d};`, `d` is not declared yet.

Comment: start with a simpler problem. create one element and print it out. then add a second and try your print operations on it.

Comment: `listelem[1]` is an `int` you don't have any `int` member in your struct so the initialization you have doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

From your code,

```
    Elem a = {listelem[0]};
    Elem b = {listelem[1],&a};
    Elem c = {listelem[2],&b,&d};    /* (X) */
    Elem d = {listelem[3],&c,&e};    /* (Y) */
```

Notice that `d` is declared in line (Y). However, you are trying to get its address at line (X), before it is defined. Which is the major cause of the error.

To fix this, just don't try to initialize while declaring; declare them all and use a `for` loop to assign them values (or manually).